# Storing large quantities of KOH

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, safety, materials

I need to handle large quantities of $\ce{KOH}$; close to 1000 liters of 85 % conc $\ce{KOH}$ for about an hour. Any suggestions on how I go about doing it? Also the temperature during the process might touch 500 degrees Celsius.

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about safety advice. We are not here for that (and should not IMHO). Please consult a professional company for advice.

Comment: @Jori I disagree that safety should be off-topic. Though I can agree that this particular case is asking about a scale where I'm rather uncomfortable having it here. Anyone handling reactions on a thousand liter scale shouldn't ask the internet for help, they should have people that know this stuff already. Anyting else would be dangerous and very likely illegal.

Comment: @Jori Safety, covering advices on personal protection during the handling on particular compounds, suggestions for alternative and less toxic reagents and the advice to better not do something at all always had their place here - for good reason. Consequently, I voted to leave the question open.

Comment: @MadScientist I should have been more careful with my wording. I agree with you. I was of course talking about the craziness of someone asking about storage of such industrial scale quantities and needing internet for safety advice. Answering this question and leaving it open would IMHO indicate that we think it is OK to ask such things here and rely on our answers. Especially since OP is not asking about theoretical procedures of storage but about actually handling 1000 LITERS of dangerously corrosive $\ce{KOH}$.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Sure I have asked a lot of safety questions  when I first came here and I'm really glad you guys helped me out (and still do!). But there is a difference between asking which type of gloves would be preferable for handling small quantities of sulfuric acid in a home lab for instance, or asking about storing an industrial scale amount of quite hazardous chemicals. Wrongly handling 1000 liters of $\ce{KOH}$, especially at elevated temperature, could very likely get you killed and perhaps also others in the neighborhood of said storage.

Comment: Besides that, I think it is very likely, as Mad Scientist already noticed, that such storage is illegal without the proper licenses and "proof of knowledge".

Comment: Ok just to clear the air. I am planning to leave my job to open a manufacturing company of my own. And yes i will be hiring professionals to help me out, but i dont think it would hurt to know a few things before so that when they start talking at least i understand a bit of they are saying. to reiterate I am not crazy enough to handle such large amounts on internet advice. 

No its not one large 1000 liter container. Actually I will be needing only 500 liters and i plan on dividing it in 5 containers. The facility will be in a industrial area with nothing around within a 700m radius.

Comment: Just to add to the above comment. There are 3 of us, one has a masters in chemistry and other a degree in marketing. I happen to be an engineer. And no, I am not going to build anything of such magnitude in my basement :P We have worked at levels of few hundred ml and for the next few months it would be under 10 lt; 500 is a yr or 2 away. Till now we have only performed at a laboratory scale. That too under the guidance of a faculty. Our guide has put us in touch with some people from the industry, while we are evaluating that I at a personal level am trying to gauge what we are getting into.

Comment: carefully read everything about 'purity' and carbonate content. While not a problem in lab setting, when it is trivial to add some more $\ce{KOH}$, tossing around such big quantities may cost. Personally, I highly recommend to have a shower nearby and a fresh set of clothes for an emergency, alkaline burns must be dealt with as fast as possible (they are worse then acidic burns).

Comment: AFAIK, alkalies dissolve most materials at elevated temperatures. I guess, that in your case the only acceptable materials are steel and silver, most other metals and ceramics will dissolve in molten alkalies.

Comment: Thanks Kluas and Steve for your invaluable advice. In spite of all the concerns and noise I feel I am wiser and 'safer.' Closing this thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various stainless steels resist boiling saturated aquous $\ce{KOH}$, such as DIN X6CrMo17 (ASI 434), DIN X5CrNi1911 (ASI 305).

Dont't forget about a suitable and sufficiently large reservoir around the tank in case of spills, valve breaks, etc.

Comment: ya sure safety first. i will be using only 500 liters but just to be safe i am going for a larger container. would you by any chance know of some reliable suppliers for these tanks?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Btw, don't forget about the (local) legal aspects of running such a facility ;)

Comment: I know in New Jersey you are required to have a holding tank around an open reaction that is 110% the size of the reacting vessel, or that's at least what my Chem prof said was required when he worked in an industrial lab. Edit: 110% the size of aka 10% larger.

Comment: This "stainless" and (expensive=ferritic) steels are a bad choice, and moreover superfluous. Any lye above ph 9 can be stored safely in mild steel. KOH it seems is sold at 45 % maximum, so most of this thread is nonsensy. And first of all, why KOH instead of much cheaper NaOH? Last not least 1000 ltrs is not a big amount, only to an amateur. 50 % NaOH is shipped in 1000 ltr PE containers or in Tank trucks/waggons/barges. If this cryptex has the company of a chem master, why does he ask here?

Comment: @Georg there is a difference between Sodium and Potassium. Ever had Potassium Chloride as table salt? Having potassium instead of sodium imparts specific properties to the final product. Hope you are smart enough to understand why not 'Na'OH. It doesn't hurt to ask around, especially when none of us have any solid industrial experience. The one with among the 3 of us who has a degree in chem is on an extended holiday in Norway. So until he comes I am doing some ground work.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing to clear up is – Why do you need to store 1000 L of KOH in liquid form? It is as others have pointed out, very concerning that someone who is planning to store this quantity needs to ask on the internet.

My advice is don't store 1000 L of liquid KOH, store 40 × 25 L of liquid KOH. This will reduce the risk considerably, and help ensure that a single leak isn't a catastrophic event, but is something you can deal with. This is a common philosophy, and is used, for example, in trailers of dangerous gases, which are organized into racks of 20 smaller gas bottles instead of one large tank.

Keep your 25 L containers off the floor in a bunded area for spill containment, and have appropriate means to deal with a spill. I'm not going to tell you the best way to handle a spill because I don't know. – You need to find out. Also, make sure the store is properly monitored to detect any problems.

---

Now, going back to my initial point: Let's accept that, for whatever reason, you need to store 1000 L of KOH (as you haven't shared with us what you are doing.) Solid KOH is much safer than liquid KOH, so why do you even need to mix up the solution all at once?

One of the causes of the Bhopal disaster (the worst industrial disaster ever, which killed many thousands of people due an uncontrolled venting event) was the unnecessary storage of a toxic and volatile compound (methyl isocyanate.) If the pesticide they were making had been synthesized via a different route, or even if the methyl isocyanate had been made only in the quantities needed, the size of the disaster could have been reduced or even eliminated (despite the extremely poor state of maintenance of the plant.)

I suggest you mix up the KOH in small batches as you need it to reduce the risk

---

> the temperature in the process might touch 500 degrees Celsius

By "process" I assume you mean mixing solid KOH with water, and that you do not actually need to use the KOH at this temperature. If you expect to reach these temperatures, you are doing it wrong. As can be seen from https://koh.olinchloralkali.com/TechnicalInformation/Phase%20Diagram%200-80.pdf KOH solution in all compositions from 0 to 85% is liquid at below 150 °C. Note also that concentrations above 50% are solid at room temperature – so do you really mean 85% conc KOH?

The safe way to do this is to add the dangerous material to the safe material, particularly as water has such a high heat capacity and can lose heat by boiling. You are going to need either a lot of patience, or mechanical screw feeder, to perform the addition at a safe rate. You will also need decent stirring equipment. Also, I would expect most of the heat will be released in mixing the first 50% of the KOH, because after that you are effectively mixing KOH with KOH.

In any case, if you are planning to do this, you should check the thermochemistry yourself and include it in your Risk Assessment, along with any relevant details from industry experience regarding specific hazards of mixing (spattering for example?)

I really hope you make sure what you doing before you do this. Alkalis are a lot worse on human flesh than acids, partly because they turn the oils in your skin to soap, and partly because the spills won't evaporate and therefore persist until something is done about them.

It would be a good idea to dye your KOH so you know where any spills are. I personally have spilt 50L of antifreeze solution in the lab (it was intentionally dyed beforehand in case of spills, and needless to say we used propylene glycol as it is much less toxic than the ethylene glycol used in car radiators.) Whatever you intend, something in your experiment will go wrong.

Please also check the legal aspects in your area. Also, consult with your supplier! The fact that you need to ask on the internet instead of talking to them suggests you are up to something unusual. Would you care to share with us what it is?

---

EDIT - Now you've clarified you're an engineer, one more very important point. Keep KOH away from aluminium. Alkali will dissolve the oxide layer that protects aluminium from corrosion, and unmask the true (very high) reactivity of the metal. A lot of heat and hydrogen gas will be generated by the reaction $\ce{3 KOH + Al -> K3AlO3 + 2/3 H2}$.

I'm guessing most stainless steels should be fine (but obviously check.) I have used equipment from the catering industry in some experiments, but stay away from stainless steel cookware that has the base thickened with aluminium. Even though it is external, it's not worth the risk.

Also, note that mixtures of acids and bases with water are often most corrosive at a medium concentration, so don't assume that just because a material is OK at 90% concentration, it's going to be OK at 50% concentration.

Comment: Hey thanks for suggesting the idea of dyeing. As mentioned in a comment above, it is in an industrial area; the legal aspect is being worked out by another friend. The temperature will be maintained only for an hour when we add the other reactant. Why i am asking is because we have performed the process only at a laboratory level under the guidance of a prof. The prof has set us up with some of his contacts in the industry. But before we scale up, i thought it would be better to seek some advice.

Comment: This is the kind of advice i was looking for :). Subtle points; something that is not covered in college education but only people with sharp eye catch. wish we could have you as another guide.

Comment: @cryptex If it was not covered during college education, you went to the wrong college. Majority of these risk concerns are 1st year collage training. I am seriously concerned about  people who need this advice: it is a serious red flag that they don't have any relevant knowledge and training.

Comment: @Greg I think the problem is they have the wrong degrees. They have a chemist, cryptex is an "engineer" but they don't have a chemical engineer or even an industrial chemist. Chemical engineers study two relevant subjects that are not on the curriculum for either chemists or mechanical engineers: 1. heat transfer and mass transfer (mixing,dissolution,precipitation) 2. analysis of chemical industry disasters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_industrial_disasters divides them between "energy" and "other." Even then, there's nothing like witnessing a small incident to help you focus in future

Comment: @steveverrill Chemists study all this or how to figure out if they don't know, it is basic lab safety. And if you don't know basic lab safety, you shouldn't do experiments, even in 10 000th of this scale.

Comment: @Greg I studied chemistry before I studied chemical engineering, and in no way did the chemistry course, even the practicals, prepare me for anything on this scale. The chemical engineering degree didn't really either, because it presented methodologies but there wasn't a lot of practice in applying them. It was, I'm afraid, working on pilot plant (under experienced supervision) that prepared me for working on pilot plant. Despite prior preparation, formal risk assessment and even HAZOP, I've seen a few incidents, all (except perhaps one) of which in hindsight were preventable.

Comment: @steveverrill The most issues are not coming from the scale. How to work with alkalies, what are the common types or dangers, what vessels you should use, you have to be careful with spills, with warming it up/boiling, how to dissolve, how to neutralize, don't keep it in aluminium vessel, you cannot boil KOH solution at 500C etc are all basic chemistry knowledge. Without that you are a loose canon in a small scale lab, too.

Comment: @Greg Sure, but the issues are much bigger on pilot scale, and there are additional issues to consider. For example, neutralizing a small spill of KOH in the lab, the heat evolved is not a huge issue, whereas on pilot scale it could well be. You need to plan & document what to do specifically for a spill of KOH - is it even practical to neutralize immediately, or do you contain? Another example from my experience: heating a non-toxic aqueous polymer solution at 10L was fine, but at 100L it unexpectedly caused a health hazard due to volatile decomposition products from localized overheating.

Comment: @steveverrill This answer (I am commenting) contains only marginal information about industrial size processes. The bigger problem is that OP seems to be not able to handle lab scale experiments, neither.

Comment: @Greg pretty sure i went to the right college (top 5). steve might be right; may not have the right degrees. Though I am elec. engineer I work at an I-bank. The project was something we undertook last year in college and have only now decided to scale up. So yes we certainly lack a lot here.

Comment: I am not being naive, I do have first hand experience from my early days in college what conc KOH can do even when you are near a bath. Like i have made it abundantly clear,we are in touch with industry experts. I am one of those who try not to get influenced by others and believe in looking for wise opinion. To an extent i had an economical motive; my firm doesn't employees to have a second job. So I have to calculate if my savings would see us through plus i wanted to be more involved . You are free to downvote or simply ignore this thread; never asked for any of you guys to build our plant.